# How Write Arabic in Photoshop?

Tags: fonts, photoshop-cs4

The characters are not connected when I write in Arabic. The characters are separated and not connected. I'm working with the ME version, I found some solutions that use templates, but I'm asking for a better solution than to use a template. **How do I find a font for Photoshop-CS4 that writes Arabic "correctly".?**

Answer (score 1):

Use [Adobe Photoshop Middle East Version](http://download.cnet.com/Adobe-Photoshop-CS4-Middle-Eastern-version/3000-2192_4-75157403.html) or use [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/).

Answer (score 1):

To make letters work correctly and in the direction from right to left, you will need to highlight text and go to **Windows** > **Character** > from this window click on the arrow on top right corner and select ( **Arabic Digits** ) and ( **Right to Left Direction** ).

Click on **Paragraph** tab in middle and also click on the arrow on top right corner, select ( Middle East Single-Line Composer ) and ( Right to Left ).

I hope this was helpful. :)